# Gnome does not load ics calendar file

Tags: calendar

translation:
Did someone else have problems uploading files to the Gnome calendar ics? If you resolved them, how did you do it? I tried only upload the file with the option "Calendar Settings" load calendar from file.

---

original:
alguien más ha tenido problemas intentando cargar archivos ics al calendario Gnome? Si han logrado hacerlo, cómo lo han hecho? He intentado únicamente cargar el archivo en "configuración del calendario" cargar calendario a partir de archivo.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include some more information. How did you try to upload files? What went wrong? Did you get error messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import your .ics file into Evolution first. It will then show up in both GNOME Calendar and GOME California as well as Maya. (All these calendars rely on Evolution for the backend.)